# How to get a specific result from the mongodb collection in Meteor

Tags: node.js, mongodb, meteor

I want to get some results that a certain field has the same value as a selectedItem value in my html. I'm using Meteor :

```
Template.Bd.helpers({
  'd': function () {
    return List.find({ 
      region: event.target.RegionValue.options[RegionValue.selectedIndex].text.value
    }).fetch();
  }        
});
```

Comment: looks good to me ;-)

Comment: How does your syntax not work?

Comment: I have this bug when I open Chrome console :

Exception in template helper: TypeError: Cannot read property 'options' of undefined

So the problem is with "options", how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

I think I just have to put the function in the template events not in the helpers

```
'change Region': function(event) { 
        return List.find({r:event.target.Region.options[Region.selectedIndex].text.value}).fetch();
      console.log("changed");
    }
```

I avoided the bug but the code is still not working.